# Windows 7 - CMD command to keep cmd open after executing

Tags: windows-7, command-line

For some reason I cannot open the cmd. I created a simple bat file that does `dir` but it immediately closes the cmd as well. Is there a way I can keep the cmd open with some command?

Comment: You mean using a batch (`.bat`) file script?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot more practical to just fix the problem of not being able to open a command prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `pause` at the end of the batch script should keep it open until you press any key to continue.

Comment: this works expect that it doesn't accept new input after completing the pause

Comment: because it closes again.

Comment: Are you running the script from the command line or double clicking it?  It would help if you provided the code for the script.

Comment: I am double clicking on it. The code doesn't matter. the problem is that I cannot run the cmd like I should be able to

Comment: The reason I asked for the code was because I wanted to see if you had an `exit` at the end.  If you're just trying to start a command prompt and have it print the directory listing first, then in your script you could do something like `start cmd /K dir`.  Run `cmd /?` for details on the `/K` option.

Comment: Adding `PAUSE` at the end does not work on windows 10. If I add `START` at the beginning as well, then it does actually pause, but then it opens 2 windows....I want to open only one. Do you know the solution for windows 10?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Windows 10 system that I can try this on, but I would be quite surprised if they removed the `pause` command.  Are you certain that the rest of the script is working correctly?  If one of the previous commands in the script is also a batch script and it's not being called by using the `call` statement, then the the script will terminate before getting to the `pause`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

Put cmd /k on the very last line of the script.